# Speed up VBA for large dataset

Tags: excel, vba, office-addins, excel-addins

I am using a VBA code to showup precedent and depedent on range by using the arrows in excel. The code work well but when i use it for large range it takes significant time and hangs up. Please suggest the ways i can change the code to make it efficient to handle large range.

```
Sub TraceDependentsAndPrecedents()
      Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", , xTxt, , , , , 8)
    
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xCell.ShowPrecedents
        xCell.ShowDependents
    Next
End Sub
```

I want to speed up the code, make it more efficient to handle the large data range. The code us arrows to highlight the precedent and dependent in excel.

Comment: What predictable error are you trying to bypass with `On Error Resume Next`? Have you tried turning off screen-updating? Can you limit your range to only cells that have formulas?

Comment: I Have Tried the screen-updating but does not worked well in terms of speed. Please suggest appropriate ways.

Comment: What about my other two questions?  And I should have changed my third question to restricting your range only to those formulas with data (values or formulas).

Comment: the code limit the range and works on user selection

Comment: I see that. I am suggesting to modify your code to limit the range to cells that only have formulas or constants. And you have still not answered my first question.

Comment: Maybe try disabling events?

Comment: There is going to be very little you can do here. Think about what you're asking it to do. When you ask for all dependents, it checks every formula across the entire workbook to see if the cell is referenced. That's the most efficient method. You could restrict your precedents search by limiting it to only cells with formulas, but it's the dependents search that takes the time.

Comment: could consider using _union_ to combine multiple cells into a range and then show precedents and dependents for the entire range. but to echo CLR's point, dependents search operation itself is inherently time-consuming anyway in handling large workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code modified to limit the cells being checked:
I don't know if there is much else you can do to speed things up.

```
Sub TraceDependentsAndPrecedents()
      Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the data range:", , xTxt, , , , , 8)
    
'limit cells to search
    Set xRg = Union(xRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), xRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xCell.ShowPrecedents
        xCell.ShowDependents
    Next
    
End Sub
```